# Google map is not showing in android

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an app where I am using maps javascript api in ionic @capacitor/google to show map.
It is working fine when I am running the app in browser. But whenever I am running the app in emulator or device the map is not displaying.

Method I am using to display google map:

```
async createMap(map: ElementRef) {
this.map = await GoogleMap.create({
  id: "capacitor-google-maps",
  element: map.nativeElement,
  apiKey: environment.googleMapsApiKey,
  config: {
    zoom: 18,
    center: this.position,
    mapTypeId: "satellite",
    disableDefaultUI: true,
  },
  forceCreate: true,
});

await this.addMarker(this.position.lat, this.position.lng);
await this.addListeners();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the [documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/google-maps?_gl=1*1bx1m8b*_ga*MTUxNDY5OTc0My4xNjY2NzY5NTc0*_ga_REH9TJF6KF*MTY2ODU3NjY0Ny40OS4xLjE2Njg1NzY2NTMuMC4wLjA.#usage) it says:

> On Android, the map is rendered beneath the entire webview, and uses this component to manage its positioning during scrolling events. This means that as the developer, you must ensure that the webview is transparent all the way through the layers to the very bottom. In a typically Ionic application, that means setting transparency on elements such as IonContent and the root HTML tag to ensure that it can be seen. If you can't see your map on Android, this should be the first thing you check.

So you need to alter your css so that it shows on Android, something like this should get the job done:

```
ion-content {
  --background: transparent;
}

body {
  background: transparent;
}
```

However, doing these css changes will cause a lot of unwanted style changes and issues. Moreover, based on my experience trying @capacitor/google-maps, I would highly recommend using [@angular/google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/google-maps) instead, as it is more developed, maintained by google and the capacitor plugin still has a long way to go.

You can check this [post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/capacitor-google-map-not-showing-on-android/228390) on ionic's forum as I had the exact same issue.

**UPDATE:**

You can check @angular/google-maps [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/google-maps/README.md), also you can check below a sample code:

HTML

```
<google-map [center]="{lat: 20, lng:20}" [options]="options" height="140px" width="auto">

    <map-marker [position]="{lat: 20, lng: 20}" [options]="markerOptions"></map-marker>

</google-map>
```

ts:

```
  markerOptions: google.maps.MarkerOptions = {
    draggable: false,
  };

  options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    draggable: false,
    clickableIcons: false, 
  };
```

You can also see Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map) to get a list of all the options for their map

Comment: @angular/google-maps package is not working for me. Can you share any sample code ?

Comment: @AriyanAshfaque I updated my answer, you can check it out.